# django queryset counts substrings in charField

Tags: django, django-models

One field in my model is a charField with the format substring1-substring2-substring3-substring4 and it can have this range of values:

```
"1-1-2-1"
"1-1-2-2"
"1-1-2-3"
"1-1-2-4"
"2-2-2-6"
"2-2-2-7"
"2-2-2-9"
"3-1-1-10"
"10-1-1-11"
"11-1-1-12"
"11-1-1-13"
```

For example I need to count the single number of occurrences for substring1.
In this case there are 5 unique occurrences (1,2,3,10,11).

```
"1-X-X-X"
"2-X-X-X"
"3-X-X-X"
"10-X-X-X"
"11-X-X-XX"
```

Sincerely I don't know where I can start from. I read the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/ but I didn't find a specific clue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain a bit better? from your example, `substring 1` (which, based on your rule, is the number '1') occurs 4 times (items 1,2,3 and 4), so I don't really get how you can have 5 and with those positions

Comment: Sorry! I just modified it. I meant counting the unique occurrences for substring1 which is the first part of the charfield (e.g. NN-).
In this case there are 5 unique occurrences 1,2,3,10,11

Comment: Ok now I understood your question, you want to count unique occurrencies for the first substring of your strings. Now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results = MyModel.objects.all()

pos_id = 0

values_for_pos_id = [res.field_to_check.split('-')[pos_id] for res in results]
values_for_pos_id = set(values_for_pos_id)
```

How does this work:

- first you fetch all your objects (`results`)
- `pos_id` is your substring index (you have 4 substring, so it's in range 0 to 3)
- you split each `field_to_check` (aka: where you store the substring combinations) on `-` (your separator) and fetch the correct substring for that object
- you convert the list to a set (to have all the unique values)

Then a simple `len(values_for_pos_id)` will do the trick for you

NB: If you don't have `pos_id` or can't set it anywhere, you just need to loop like this:

```
for pos_id in range(4):
    values_for_pos_id = set([res.field_to_check.split('-')[pos_id] for res in results])
    # process your set results now
    print len(values_for_pos_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
# Assumes your model name is NumberStrings and attribute numbers stores the string.
search_string = "1-1-2-1"
matched_number_strings = NumberStrings.objects.filter(numbers__contains=search_string)
num_of_occurrences = len(matches_found)
matched_ids = [match.id for match in matched_number_strings]
```

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. I don't have an input search string. I need to count all unique occurrences for the substring1. See my modified question.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through these items (I guess they're strings), and add the value of each substring_*n* to a Set_*n*.

Since set values are unique, you would have a set, called `Set_1`, for example, that contains 1,2,3,10,11.

Make sense?